# Generating pdf from html using jsPDF, nested lists

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

This is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body > 
        <ol>
            <li>First item</li>
            <li>Second item</li>
            <li>Third item
                <ol>
                    <li>Indented item</li>
                    <li>Indented item</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Fourth item</li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the generated pdf:

[image]

This is my code:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
this.savePdf(doc);
doc.fromHTML(template, 10, 3, { 'width': 190 }); //template is html
doc.save(`name.pdf`);
```

Please let me know if there's a way to convert html that contains a nested list to a pdf in Angular. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You can probably simplify this example: the unordered list is completely separate from the ordered list, and probably isn't making any difference. The real problem appears to be that the library is ignoring the `start` attribute on the `<ol>` element. That said, maybe it would work if you _did_ nest the `<ul>` inside the `<ol>`?

Comment: I updated the example.